# How to use Qt Windget in the Win32 application?

Tags: windows, qt, visual-c++

I'd like to present a data for some `Visual c++` `Windows` project with a simple graphic table form. I think about using the `Qt library` `QTableWidget` to achieve that. I just have added support for `Qt` for the project (as it wasn't created as a `Qt` project at all).

Can someone please provide me the simplest, minimal code to use `QTableWidget` inside my main `wWinMain` function (I'd move the code latter but for now I'd like to test the Widget just inside the main function).

There are examples showing hove to implement the `QTableWidget` but all of them utilizes the `Qt Creator` or `Python` implementation while what i have to do is to add this widget functionality to the excising `Win32` `c++` project.

Please help!

Comment: At the very least you should try searching through the [examples provided](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html): perhaps the ["Color Editor Factory Example"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-coloreditorfactory-example.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it is not practical to use QT in Visual Studio without an integration extension such as QT VS Tools.
However, it is possible. Here is a minimal example to draw QTableWidget in wWinMain by using Visual Studio.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QtWidgets/QTableWidget>

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    int argc = 0;
    char** argv = nullptr;

    // Convert wide character command-line arguments to regular character
    int wargc;
    LPWSTR* wargv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &wargc);
    if (wargv) {
        argv = new char* [wargc];
        for (int i = 0; i < wargc; ++i) {
            int len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wargv[i], -1, nullptr, 0, NULL, NULL);
            argv[i] = new char[len];
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wargv[i], -1, argv[i], len, NULL, NULL);
        }
        argc = wargc;
        LocalFree(wargv); // Free the memory allocated by CommandLineToArgvW
    }

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // Create a Qt application window
    QMainWindow window;
    window.setWindowTitle("Qt QTableWidget Example");
    window.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600);

    // Create a QTableWidget
    QTableWidget tableWidget(&window);
    tableWidget.setGeometry(10, 10, 780, 580);

    // Set the number of rows and columns
    tableWidget.setRowCount(4);
    tableWidget.setColumnCount(3);

    // Populate the table with data
    tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 1, Column 1"));
    tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 1, Column 2"));
    tableWidget.setItem(0, 2, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 1, Column 3"));

    tableWidget.setItem(1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 2, Column 1"));
    tableWidget.setItem(1, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 2, Column 2"));
    tableWidget.setItem(1, 2, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 2, Column 3"));

    tableWidget.setItem(2, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 3, Column 1"));
    tableWidget.setItem(2, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 3, Column 2"));
    tableWidget.setItem(2, 2, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 3, Column 3"));

    tableWidget.setItem(3, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 4, Column 1"));
    tableWidget.setItem(3, 1, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 4, Column 2"));
    tableWidget.setItem(3, 2, new QTableWidgetItem("Row 4, Column 3"));

    // Show the main window
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I tested this code with Visual Studio 2019 CE and 32 bit QT 5.15 (Shared build for VS2019).

You need to add QT include path e.g. C:\Qt\5.15.2_msvc2019_x86_shared\include to Additional Include Directories and add QT lib path to Linker Additional Directories e.g. C:\Qt\5.15.2_msvc2019_x86_shared\lib. Also add Qt5Cored.lib, Qt5Guid.lib and Qt5Widgetsd.lib libs (assuming that you will use debug libs) to link. Make sure that Linker->System->SubSystem is Windows. You can set Debugging Working Directory as QT bin directory e.g C:\Qt\5.15.2_msvc2019_x86_shared\bin to run this code in debug session to prevent dll not found errors.